# Excel VBA- Copying Data To Another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Typically copying data between workbooks is a fairly simple task, however I have been having trouble doing so which I believe is a result of the way I am finding data or inserting it into the intended file. I have a .iqy file that gives me a list with all the workbooks and their filepaths on my SharePoint site. My code then stitches the information from this query together to give me a filepath to follow to the workbook I need to collect information from. This macro will open each file, take the intended information, and output it into the original file that I am running the macro from. For one point of information, I am trying to copy the contents of a cell below a header (which has changed position between versions of the files I am searching) and paste it into the output row. It is supposed to identify a cell with a unique word ("Herstellkosten") in the formula and copy the value below it. I have tested the code in multiple ways, and think it is finding the right cell to copy then finding the right cell to paste to, but each time no data appears. Any ideas why this could be? Also, please excuse the extra gore in my code below, I am still working on removing unneeded parts from code I am basing this on.

```
Option Explicit
Dim strMasterWorkbook As String
Dim strLinkWbk As String
Dim strImportSheet As String
Dim strQueryPath As String
Dim strCurrentFilePath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strCurrentFile As String
Dim intLine As Integer
Dim intExtLine As Integer
Dim intFound As Integer
Dim intSheets As Integer
Dim intLastLine As Integer
Dim dtCurrentFileModified As Date
Dim intLastLine2 As Integer
Dim intLine2 As Integer
Dim intImport As Integer
Dim intLoc As Integer
Dim strCurrentLocation As String
Dim countentry, countfound, n As Integer
Dim count_intLastLine_n1, intFound_n1, intLastLine_n1 As Integer
Dim fst_Del_Date, Org_Date, MufCost_Part, MufCost_Tool, Hours_PPP, Part_num, Planer_name, Description As Variant
Dim strFirstAddress As String
Dim searchlast As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim search As Range
Dim FolderNme As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim rngFindValue As Variant

'Yellow
Sub Marine()
MsgBox "Update may take several minutes. Select OK to continue."
On Error Resume Next

'Clear Old Data
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A2:I100000").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("K2:Z100000").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A2").Select

Dim Worksheet As Object
Dim Workbook As Object
Dim FldrWkbk As Object
Dim FolderNme As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim OutputRow As Integer
Dim StartRange As String
Dim EndRange As String
Dim ManuCost As Range
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = sht("Project-Overview").Range("A3:Z3")

strMasterWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
strImportSheet = "QueryPaths"
strQueryPath = Sheets("QueryLocation").Range("QueryLocation").Value

Sheets(strImportSheet).Select
If Not Range("A1").Value = "" Then
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
End If

Workbooks.Open strQueryPath

strLinkWbk = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Selection.Copy

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets(strImportSheet).Select
Sheets(strImportSheet).Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Workbooks(strLinkWbk).Close SaveChanges:=False

With Sheets(strImportSheet)

filepath = strCurrentFilePath
OutputRow = 1
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & OutputRow).Activate
OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
For intLine = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If VBA.Right(.Cells(intLine, 1), 4) = "xlsm" Then
        strCurrentFilePath = "https://fect/" & .Cells(intLine, 5) & "/" & .Cells(intLine, 1)
        dtCurrentFileModified = .Cells(intLine, 2)
        intLoc = 0
        strFileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QueryPaths").Cells(intLine, 1)
        Set FldrWkbk = Workbooks.Open(strCurrentFilePath, False, True)

        For Each sht In FldrWkbk.Sheets
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
'Cal Sheets
          If sht.Name Like "Cal Sheet*" Then

            'Tool Price
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("N" & OutputRow) = sht.Range("C12")
            'RFQ or POCS
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("T" & OutputRow) = sht.Range("I4")
            'Part Piece Price
'-------------------Part of Code in Question-------------------------
            Cells.Find(What:="*Herstellkosten*", LookIn:=xlFormulas).Select
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("O" & OutputRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
          End If

            Next sht
            FldrWkbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next
End With
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Starting Position
Sheets("PlannerData").Select
Range("B2").Select
MsgBox "Update Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: your **Code in Question** seems to be alright. are you sure, your selection has value?

Comment: You may consider commenting out  `On Error Resume Next` to see if an error is occurring that you may not be aware of.

Comment: @tretom The selection is the result of a formula, however it should always have value. I tried carrying out the same procedure of searching, copying, and pasting within the source workbook and had no issues which leads me to believe something happens between the workbooks...

Comment: @RyanL That was a good call, it came up with an error highlighting 'sht.Cells.Find(What:="*Herstellkosten*", LookIn:=xlFormulas).Select' saying "Select method of Range class failed". Any ideas?

Comment: can you specify the sheet you're running a search on?  e.g. `sht.Cells.Find(What:=Herstelkosten*", LookIn:=xlFormulas).Select`

Comment: @RyanL unfortunately the sheet names vary wildly with the only similarity being that they contian "Cal Sheet". I've tried using your example but it didn't do they trick

Comment: In the example code above, you use just `Cells.Find...`  What I mean is it looks like you define the sheet you're working in (`sht`).  Can you append `sht` before `Cells.Find...`?